# My image's clipping paths are not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg

I am attempting to use two images, cutting one diagonally in half using a clipping path(div id="umn") and laying it over the first image (applied as a background image on the body tag).

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div id="umn">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{background:url(../images/unl.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
 #umn{width:100%;height:100%;background:url(../images/umn.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);}
```

You can see it live here:
http://wheresthechair.com/

This works great in Chrome, but the problem is that these clipping paths do not appear to work in Firefox. In Firefox the user just sees the #unm div at 100% height and width, without the clipping path applied.

It has been suggested using SVG to create the clipping path, but I am unable to do so. I cannot grasp the concept of the point coordinates and there seems to be a difference in chrome and Firefox still, regardless.
I tried the following HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="umn"><img src="assets/images/umn.jpg" /></div>
       <svg width='0' height='0'>
         <defs>
            <clipPath id="clipping" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
               <polygon points="0 0, 3 0, 1 1, 1 1" />
            </clipPath>
         </defs>
       </svg>
</body>
```

Paired with the following CSS:

```
body{background:url(../images/unl.jpg)no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
 #umn{
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#clipping");
  clip-path: url("#clipping");
position: fixed;
  width: 100%;}
  #unm img{width: 100%;height: auto;}
```

You can see this attempt is not even close, here: http://wheresthechair.com/svg/index.html

(Yes, I know the images are huge, going to downsize)

How can I get this working in major browsers and maintain responsiveness?
Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: You should provide your code in a snippet within your question - in the future your link (and the code with it) will have changed, and your question will be useless to future viewers.

Comment: a) provide a [mcve] in the question, not a website. b) if you mean CSS clipping that's still under development. SVG clipping is available. c) what is supposed to be clipped by the element with id="clipping"?

Comment: I don't see how this fails to meet the MCV request.

Comment: There are three elements on the page, I will comment out the extraneous one if it is getting in the way. There is no way not to see the issue when viewing in Firefox.

To your question c) You can see that the #clipping element is used as a clip path on #unm as per the example above.

Comment: Is the element with the id="clipping" in the same file as clip-path: url("#clipping"); if not it won't work.